# Obtaining the coordinates of a timestamp from a KML file based on the video's current time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kml

I created a custom video player that, when playing a video, extracts coordinates from a KML file based on the video's current time. I started by reading the KML file, specifying the initial date of the kml , so that every time the video plays, I can retrieve the initial time and add the video's elapsed time to it, creating a timestamp within the KML. The issue with this approach is that it only retrieves the location for the initial time and I cannot obtain more data. Here's a snippet of the code...

```
const extractCoordsKml = () => {
        const kmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(kmlInfo?.kml, "application/xml");
        if (!kmlDocument) return null;
        const errors = kmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
        if (errors.length > 0) return null;
        const placemark: any = kmlDocument.querySelector('Placemark');
        if (!placemark) return null;
        const timestampsStr = placemark.querySelector('Data[name="timestamp"] value').textContent;
        const latitudesStr = placemark.querySelector('Data[name="LATITUDE"] value').textContent;
        const longitudesStr = placemark.querySelector('Data[name="LONGTITUDE"] value').textContent;
        const altitudesStr = placemark.querySelector('Data[name="ALTITUDE"] value').textContent;
        const timestamps = timestampsStr.split(',');
        const latitudes = latitudesStr.split(',').map(parseFloat);
        const longitudes = longitudesStr.split(',').map(parseFloat);
        const altitudes = altitudesStr.split(',').map(parseFloat);
        const currentTime = media?.currentTime;
        if (!currentTime) return null;
        if (!kmlInfo?.data_voo) return null;
        const voo_data = parseISO(kmlInfo.data_voo);
        const currentTimeInMilliseconds = currentTime * 1000;
        const currentTimeISO:Date = addMilliseconds(voo_data, currentTimeInMilliseconds);
        const currentTimeISOFormatted:string= format(currentTimeISO, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        for(let i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
         if(timestamps[i].includes(currentTimeISOFormatted) ) {
           return {
            latitude: latitudes[i],
            longitude: longitudes[i],
            altitude: altitudes[i]
         };
    }
}
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I recreated the method for reading the kml, i checked that each timestamp matches the a specific position on the coordinates, so i got first item of the timestamps and add by the seconds on the video, and found the position that corresponded to that answer.
```

```js
            useEffect(() => {
        if (path && kml) {
            const kmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(kml, "application/xml");
            if (!kmlDocument) return;
            const errors = kmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("parsererror");
            if (errors.length > 0) return;
            const placemark: any = kmlDocument.querySelector('Placemark');
            if (!placemark) return;
            const timestampsStr = placemark.querySelector('Data[name="timestamp"] value').textContent;
            const coordinatesStr = placemark.querySelector('LineString coordinates').textContent;
            const timestamps: string[] = timestampsStr.split(',');
            const coordinates: string[] = coordinatesStr.split(/\s+/);
            setKmlData(() => (
                { coordinates, timestamps }
            ))
        }
    }, [kml])
        
        
        const extractCurrentPositionKml = () => {
        const currentTime = media?.currentTime;
        if (!currentTime) return null;
        const voo_data = parseISO(kmlData?.timestamps[0]); 
        const currentTimeInMilliseconds = currentTime * 1000;
        const currentTimeISO: Date = addMilliseconds(voo_data, currentTimeInMilliseconds);
        let closestIndex = -1;
        let closestTimestampDiff = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
        kmlData?.timestamps.forEach((t:any, index:number) => {
            const timestamp = parseISO(t);
            const timestampDiff = Math.abs(timestamp.getTime() - currentTimeISO.getTime());
            
            if (timestampDiff < closestTimestampDiff) {
                closestIndex = index;
                closestTimestampDiff = timestampDiff;
            }
        });
        if (closestIndex === -1) return null;
        const coords = kmlData?.coordinates[closestIndex].split(',').map(parseFloat);
        if (coords.length >= 3) {
            return {
                latitude: coords[1],
                longitude: coords[0],
                altitude: coords[2]
            };
        }
    
        return null;
    }
```

in a useeffect and getting it in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).